# How to use Retrofit library for Get and Post methods in android?

Tags: android, retrofit

I need to use Retrofit library for parsing the data from URL and Post the data to server by passing some Parameters.I tried some links but i did not understand that clearly. Can any one explain how to use retrofit? and Suggest any best links for retrofit which are related to latest version.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Official Site](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Comment: [checkout this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=siq2_5U-a20)

Comment: @Droid your link unavailable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was developing a prototype application where I tested the Retrofit. I will just provide you the associated code and requirements.

```
private void testRetrofit() throws IOException
{
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    DemoEndpointInterface endpoint = retrofit.create(DemoEndpointInterface.class);
    Call<DemoUser> call = endpoint.getUser("1");

    DemoUser user = call.execute().body();

    Log.d("$$$$ID : ", user.getId());
    Log.d("$$$$User ID : ", user.getUserId());
    Log.d("$$$$Title : ", user.getTitle());
    Log.d("$$$$Body : ", user.getBody());

    //Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), user.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Declare an interface as mentioned below:

```
public interface DemoEndpointInterface {
@GET("/posts/{userId}")
Call<DemoUser> getUser(@Path("userId") String userid);   }
```

The DemoUser.java is as below:

```
public class DemoUser {
String userId;
String id;
String title;
String body;

public DemoUser(String userId, String id, String title, String body) {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.body = body;
}

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getBody() {
    return body;
}

public void setBody(String body) {
    this.body = body;
}
}
```

Declare the dependencies in your app level gradle file :

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
```

Hope this helps. Let know for any issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi i did not understand what u have passed to Get method there. Can you please tell me.

Comment: Hi. Do you mean getUser("1")? Well that is basically an online service that i used to fetch a json for the poc. The {userId} in the interface is replaced by "1" and the url invoked is [http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1). Is it clear?

Comment: sorry not that . actually you have passed one string to Get mathod right. I asked about this how we have to pass this for different  URL's @GET("/posts/{userId}")

Comment: Your base url would be http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com which is defined when initializing the Retrofit instance. After your base url, the string in the GET annotation is appended. In this case after appending the base url and the GET url you will get [http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/{userId}](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/{userId}). Since we used a binding with the path variable {userId} with the parameter passed to the getUser method, so the value "1" that is passed as parameter with be placed in place of {userId}.

Answer (score 0):

Before i settle ob this retrofit has not well suported the new release so retrofit 19 is cool .
I magine You know how to insert json into a class model.So with this i will show you how to pass $DepartmentID=$_GET['DepartmentID']

First initialize this to use the api,folder1/getDepartmentDetailsSingle.php?departmentID=departmentID

```
public interface RetrofitInternetApi {
@GET("/folder1/getDepartmentDetailsSingle.php")
    void getDepartmentByID(@Query("departmentID") int departmentID,  Callback<Response> callback);
}
```

then the function is

```
public void GetSINGLEDepartment(int departmentid){
 RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(
                ROOT_URL).build();

        //create an instance of the VehicleAPIService.
        RetrofitInternetApi retrofitInternetApi = restAdapter
                .create(RetrofitInternetApi.class);
        retrofitInternetApi.getDepartmentByID(departmentid, new Callback<Response>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Response response, Response response2) {
                BufferedReader reader = null;

                //An string to store output from the server
                String output = "";

                try {
                    //Initializing buffered reader
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response2.getBody().in()));

                    //Reading the output in the string
                    output = reader.readLine();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.d("Success",output);

                if(isJSONValid(output)==true){
                    //Saving to THE DATABASE
                    Log.d("FOUND JSON",output);



                }else{
                    //data found is not Json
                    Log.d("NO JSON FOUND",output);

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
              Log.d("ERROR",error.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

Later as i develop i will update how to use it in realm having the json.